# Data Frame Property options have changed

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, arcmap, cartography

I have Googled and searched ESRI help files and experimented until I am blue, not to mention reloading ArcGIS Desktop10 for Repair and adding the SP5 to it. I no longer have the options of border or background for data frame in layout view. I used to -- and now don't. I don't know what changed it yet it is impossible for me to combine data frame layers with the data frame borders visible. This is what I see when I right click on the data frame properties Both on the data frame in the layout view and on the data frame in the TOC in layout view:   What happened and how do I fix it? Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I googled a bit and found this:

["To resolve, go to the 'Layout' toolbar and select the 'Change Layout', select one of the templates"](https://geonet.esri.com/thread/21501)

Have you tried it?

Answer (score -2):

Not 100% sure I understand your question.  However, from the screenshot, if you are looking to get access to the Border control at the lower right...you need to change the Clip Options to "Clip to Shape"

Comment: I believe the OP is searching for the missing "Frame" tab in the Data Frame Properties window.

Comment: Have you tried deleting the Normal.mxt?